# conversion failed varchar to int

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Below is the code for combo box selected value change. It is supposed to pick up a value from DB and display it in a text box.

```
protected void cmbPujaName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                            
    SqlConnection con2 = null;
    con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRKBSDB"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter pamt = new SqlDataAdapter("select Amount from PoojaDietyMaster where PoojaName =" + cmbPujaName.SelectedValue, con2);
    DataSet pamtds = new DataSet();
    pamt.Fill(pamtds); ......... Error shown here...........
    txtAmount.Text = pamtds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString();            
}
```

Comment: Please add the error to your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing quotes but... **do not do that like this**. This way is like leaving your door wide open and invite thieves inside for a tea party. Or SQL Injection attack, inviting hackers to steal your whole database and/or server and take full control over it.

Have such code instead:

```
SqlDataAdapter pamt = new SqlDataAdapter("select Amount from PoojaDietyMaster where PoojaName = @name", con2);
pamt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", cmbPujaName.SelectedValue);
DataSet pamtds = new DataSet();
pamt.Fill(pamtds);
```

This way you won't have to mess around with quotes, plus you're better protected against hackers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried the code its unable to display the value in the textbox. txtAmount.Text = pamtds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString();
It says IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @Rajiv that's a totally different problem. It means you don't have any records in "PoojaDietyMaster" that contain exact match to the selected value of "cmbPujaName" drop down. Debug the code and see what is this selected value. Note SQL match is case sensitive as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I was querying the PujaName column for selected value returned as ID column value. Changing the query to right column name did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's a better practice to write a query using SqlCommand parameters by mentioning proper datatype to avoid sql injection attacks. Try to handle null values as well.

```
SqlDataAdapter pamt = new SqlDataAdapter("select Isnull(Amount,0.0) Amount from PoojaDietyMaster where PoojaName = @name", con2);
pamt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbPujaName.SelectedValue.tostring();

DataSet pamtds = new DataSet();

pamt.Fill(pamtds);
```